# Failing to save or close resource created and giving memory leak issue

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I'm getting memory leak issue for below C# code, what this mean and how to fix it. I'm already using `using` block.

> Failing to save or close resource created by new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType = 'USB'") leaks it

```
using (var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType = 'USB'").Get())
        {
           foreach (var drive in managementObjectSearcher){}

        }
```

Comment: do you  know what is in `dispose` method of the class which is a return type of  `ManagementObjectSearcher("").Get()` ?

Comment: Have you  tried moving your .Get() method to the foreach statement?(`foreach (var drive in managementObjectSearcher).Get()`)

Comment: How did you conclude this is a memory leak ? As per accepted answer too, Finalization would still be triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not disposing the `ManagementObjectSearcher`; you're disposing the result of the `Get` method call. Try this:

```
using (var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
             "select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType = 'USB'"))
using (var collection = managementObjectSearcher.Get())
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Excelent, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would this lead to memory leak, Finalization would still trigger in, essentially what OP is looking at is memory spike or linear increase due to no explicit Dispose being called

Comment: @MrinalKamboj What the finalizer does is an implementation detail. The contract for `IDisposable` explicitly says that objects implementing `IDisposable` *must* be disposed explicitly, so that's what you should do. There's always the example of the `X509Store` (and the other classes dealing with X509 certificates) that didn't have finalizers despite them being absolutely necessary (sadly, they didn't even implement `IDisposable`). If there's a dispose method you're supposed to call, call it. Don't rely on finalizers. There's no guarantee they'll ever run.

Comment: @Luaan thanks for the details, I get your perspective, but there's no way to handle developer always calling dispose, that's just a recommendation and as far as Finalization is concerned, GC is bound to call it, if not explicitly suppressed, case you have mentioned is very specific. For me bigger challenge is OP calling it memory leak, which in my view is incorrect, at most it would be a spike in memory, till finalization kicks in